# jhipster - weird webpack error while working on react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jhipster

I just spun up a jhipster project with react and I am getting this error from the webpack dev server:
Andrews-MBP:familyhomestay andrewcarre$ yarn start
yarn run v1.3.2

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.3.2
$ yarn run webpack:dev
$ yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --profile --port=9060
warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --profile --port=9060
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/andrewcarre/Desktop/familyhomestay/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Andrews-MBP:familyhomestay andrewcarre$
```

I didn't change anything within the webpack configs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used npm to install recompose instead of yarn. After a project rebuilt everything is now working.

I guess yarn is not a complete drop in replacement for npm.

Comment: Yarn is the default choice for JHipster apps so it should work as expected.  Based on your error message it sounds like `yarn install` during generation failed (or if you used JHipster Online you have to run it yourself)